# How to rebase entire master branch of git repo

Tags: git, github, rebase, feature-branch

I am pretty new to git, so I apologize if this is a simple solution.

I need to rebase the entire master branch of a repo to a feature branch. The repo was made, then someone used master as the first feature branch. So, what I have now is:

```
A -- B -- C -- D (branch: master)
```

and what I would like to do is

```
  A--B--C--D (branch: new-feature)
 /
Z (branch: master)
```

where Z represents a commit containing just a .gitignore file (or some other "repo-initializing commit" ... I'd even take a blank commit containing no files, but I don't think git likes/allows that).

I understand how to rebase commits *within* a branch, so I understand how to do this:

```
     C--D (branch: new-feature)
    /
A--B (branch: master)
```

but I have not been able to figure out how to rebase all of master onto a feature branch. I believe the crux of the issue I keep facing is that I don't have any commit to point master at, since there is no Z commit (commit A has partial feature implementation, so I can't use A in place of Z).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why bother rebasing?  Just merge the new master base at the new feature tip.  With `master` checked out (to provide a decent starting point)

```
git checkout -B feature
git branch -f master   $(git commit-tree -m 'Initial commit.' `:|git mktree`)
git merge -s ours --allow-unrelated-histories   master
```

producing

```
A ... D---E     feature
         /
        Z       master
```

and now history reflects exactly what happened, everything works.

If you really want to do the rebase, [as the doc points out there's a `--root` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---root):

```
git checkout -B feature
git branch -f master   $(git commit-tree -m 'Initial commit.' `:|git mktree`)
git rebase --root --onto master
```

which will cause heartache if any branches off of the old `master` (the new `feature`) exist anywhere.